# How to allow Azure users to create RG withou seeing other RG?

Tags: access-control, azure-resource-manager

Any idea how to grant permission to Azure users to be able to create their own resources group without allowing them to see any other existing resource groups in our directory?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) enables fine-grained access management for Azure. Using RBAC, you can grant only the amount of access that users need to perform their jobs.You grant access from within the resource, resource group, or subscription that is the scope of the role assignment.

For  more information you may refer this article :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure